# Calculate change rate of Time Series values

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have an application which writes Time Series data to Elasticsearch. The (simplified) data looks like the following:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1425369600000,
    "shares": 12271
},
{
    "timestamp": 1425370200000,
    "shares": 12575
},
{
    "timestamp": 1425370800000,
    "shares": 12725
},
...
```

I now would like to use an aggregation to calculate the change rate of the `shares` field by time "buckets", for example like

The change rate of the share values within the last 10 minute "bucket" could be IMHO calculated as

```
# of shares t1
--------------
# of shares t0
```

I tried the Date Histogram aggregation, but I guess that's not what I need to calculate the change rates, because this would only give me the `doc_count`, and it's not clear to me how I could calculate the change rate from these:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "shares_over_time" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "timestamp",
                "interval" : "10m"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve my goal with aggregations within Elasticsearch? I search the docs, but didn't find a matching method.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Hi Tobi, Were you able to solve this problem? Could you please share an update?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is hard to achieve with out-of-the-box aggregate functions. However, you can take a look at [percentile_ranks_aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-rank-aggregation.html) and add your own modifications to the script to to create point in time rates.

Also, sorry for the off-top, but I wonder: is the elastic search the best fit for that kind of stuff? As I understand, at any given point in time you need only the previous sample data to calculate the correct rate for the current sample. This sounds to me like a better fit for some [sliding window algorithm](http://www.algorithmsandme.com/2014/03/heaps-sliding-window-problem.html#.VPV9OPnF_JI) real time implementation (even on some relational DB like Postgres), where you keep a fixed number of time buckets and counters you are interested in inside the bucket. Once the new sample 'arrives', you update (slide) the window and calculate the updated rate for the most recent time bucket.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I want to calculate a chart from the change rates, for example for the last 100 data points. I could filter the `timestamp` field. I'd really like to use ES, though I couldn't find a solution yet. I know that InfluxDB for example has a `dfference()` function which does what I want to achieve (http://influxdb.com/docs/v0.8/api/aggregate_functions.html#difference), but I kind of hesitate to add another technology to my stack.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to influxdb! If it is impossible to calculate and store the rate at the time of event, then implementing it on elasticsearch most likely will require some scripting. Good Luck!